# Swift 3: Find out, if the date has changed - how?

Tags: ios, iphone, date, swift3

For my app, I need to find out if the date changed in relation to the last time that you opened the app. For that reason, I made that you can see below. The problem is: it doesn't work for any reason. My app counts the days in a row that you used it so it adds one to a counter of days if the days changed.

Here's my bool:

```
var dateChanged: Bool
{
    let dateNow = Date()
    var oldDate = defaults.object(forKey: "oldDate2") as? Date

    if dateNow != oldDate
    {
        return true
    }
    else
    {
        return false
    }

    oldDate = newDate
    defaults.set(oldDate, forKey: "oldDate")
    defaults.synchronize()

}
```

How could I improve that bool? At `oldDate = newDate` it says: 'Will never be executed.'. Can you help me?

Thank you for having a look!

Comment: You are retrieving "oldDate2" but setting "oldDate".  Also there is no need to call `synchronize`

Comment: Don't you get a warning about code which will never be executed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `Calendar` method [`isDateInToday`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/calendar/2293243-isdateintoday) to check date is today's date. Also you need to put the code before returning value from function.

```
if !Calendar.current.isDateInToday(oldDate) {
    defaults.set(Date(), forKey: "oldDate")
    return true
}
return false
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to know if the date has changed, use `UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification`

reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623059-significanttimechangenotificatio

Answer (score 1):

@Whazzup - the problem is that you execute `return` before you try to set the date - that's why it will never be executed.  You only need the return for the case where the dates are equal, and you don't need to do anything else.